# Save XmlWriter file name to variable

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to save the newly created file name to a variable so I can pass it as a parameter to an upload task once it's finished writing.

"dateTimeFormat" is generated dynamically when the task is called, so file name has to be a variable.

```
var dateTimeFormat = now.ToString(_tsFormat); //special formatting of date, can be any format for demo

if (results != null)
{
    try
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create($"{_configuration.Value.FileLocation}InventoryImportPart-{dateTimeFormat}.xml"))
        {
            filename = Path.GetFileName(writer); //trying to save file name
            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                XNode productNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(item.ToString(), "data");
                productNode.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            
            //Code calling upload task with filename as parameter
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Exception when getting CosmosDB events: {e}");
    }
}
```

Should be super easy, but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Isn't this `$"{_configuration.Value.FileLocation}InventoryImportPart-{dateTimeFormat}.xml"` the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch things around: generate the filename and remember that in the variable, then use the variable in `XmlWriter.Create`:

```cs
filename = $"{_configuration.Value.FileLocation}InventoryImportPart-{dateTimeFormat}.xml";
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename))
{
    ...
}
```